# Should I add extra protection to 74HC4067

Tags: multiplexer

I plan on using a [74HC4067](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/74HC_HCT4067.pdf) to add have more analog & digital inputs on my SBC.
The datasheet talks about having built-in ESD. The analog inputs would be fed 1.8V. The digital ones would be fed 3.3V.

I have a [nice article](https://www.digikey.com/en/articles/protecting-inputs-in-digital-electronics) on how to protect digital inputs. It mentions current limiting, filtering and external clipping diode.

My interpretation is I don't need the clipping diode because it's already provided by the multiplexer. Additionally, it seems to me that the filtering could be done "after" the multiplexer (so on it's output side), which means I need only 1 filter instead of 16. And I'm not too sure about the current limiting part.

(My use case involves long wires, sometimes beyond 20m).

Can I skip the clamping diodes?
Can I have the filter and the current limit after the multiplexer?

[image: Schematics]

(16 inputs of the MUX go to one analog input of the Arduino... so here the question is what protection does the mux need, and as an extra, what does the Arduino need)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

long wires act as antennas. ESD is one problem, EMC is another. Then there is lightning. The degree of protection really depends on the environment.

The ESD diodes on ics only provide a small amount of protection and are inadequate for wires that go out into the real world. Putting protection after the mux is useless.

For a commercial design, we determine the expected environment for our device and apply the appropriate standards that guide what level of protection is required. For a hobby project, we don't need to go to that length, but is good practice to follow.

We also need to specify what the expected signals are - frequency range, impedance voltage, current and so on as this guides us as to what techniques we can use for protection. Minimal protection would be a RC filter and maybe TVS diodes, varistors etc. As well, the type of wiring - shielded? etc.

As well, hardware is only part of the solution. Your software needs to filter adc values, debounce/filter digital inputs to ensure the rest of your code responds to valid inputs. The old maxim 'garbage in/garbage out' applies. None of this is particularly difficult (usually!) but if considered during the design phase makes the likelihood of a successful project much greater.

Or you can simply ignore all of this. If so you can expect the following:

1. noisy signals. Mobile phones might give random interference.
2. nearby lightning strikes might damage the circuitry
3. ESD might damage the circuitry
4. Induction from nearby mains wiring etc can couple and induce significant interference.
5. devices turning on an off inducing noise into your signals

Comment: My question here is specific to 74HC4067. As far as I understand, I can typically do the RC filter (which is intended to denoise/debounce) after the mux and before the input. From your answer, I get that ESD (clamping diodes) are required (and before mux), but I'm unsure if RC filter HAS TO BE before the mux (which means I need 16 filters, while after the mux, I need only one).

Comment: the RC filter has to be before the mux. How else is it going to provide any sort of protection? Besides, in terms of filtering, having the filter after the mux increases settling time and limits the speed at which you can sample the channels. Note that there is nothing particularly specific to the 74HC4067 - its inputs and protection are similar to most other ics.

Comment: Add an excerpt of your schematics. It's not clear if you have 16 pins to protect or just one. In principle, all pins that go directly to the board's connector have to be protected.

Comment: Thanks, added schematics. I am note sure if the RC adds a protection that the muxer needs, or that only the Arduino need, hence the "side"...

Comment: The 4067 is facing the outside world and requires protection. The Arduino input is only driven by the 4067, so no extra protection needed there.

Comment: I guess my wonder (reading that article I gave a link to) is: what extra protection does the RC filter give (compared to simply having a resistor)? I understand it helps for instance debouncing. But does it add a protection?

Comment: It can add a degree of protection. It will help to filter out RF and hopefully soak up the average static discharge. You’ve got some keywords you can Google on for more information or some of the more learned contributors here might give you the math behind it all.

Comment: @user1532080 The capacitor helps against ESD. ESD shoots some energy in *very* short into your circuit. Without that cap, the energy that passes through the resistor needs to be dissipated in that very short time. A capacitor is able to quickly capture that energy without the voltage getting dangerously high. This provides extra time for the clamping diode, so it can safely get rid of the energy.